# Error while using Logback in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, logback

**What am I are trying to do???**

I am adding a logger in my spring boot application using Logback.

**What I have done so far?**

I added the below in application properties

```
logging.config=classpath:logback-dev.xml
```

And this is my logback configuration

```
logback-dev.xml
<configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <!-- Console Appender -->
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss a} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <!-- File Appender -->
        <File name="File"
            fileName="D:/logs/myApp.log">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss a} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </File>
         <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss} %thread %level %logger{15} %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <logger name="com.test" level="DEBUG"
            additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="File" />
        </logger>
    </Loggers>
</configuration>
```

While running the application, I got the below exception.

```
Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'classpath:logback-dev.xml'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected:
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@3:13 - no applicable action for [Appenders], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Appenders]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@5:47 - no applicable action for [Console], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Appenders][Console]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@7:79 - no applicable action for [PatternLayout], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Appenders][Console][PatternLayout]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@11:65 - no applicable action for [File], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Appenders][File]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@13:79 - no applicable action for [PatternLayout], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Appenders][File][PatternLayout]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@15:13 - no applicable action for [encoder], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Appenders][encoder]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@16:22 - no applicable action for [pattern], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Appenders][encoder][pattern]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@19:11 - no applicable action for [Loggers], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Loggers]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@21:23 - no applicable action for [logger], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Loggers][logger]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@22:33 - no applicable action for [AppenderRef], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Loggers][logger][AppenderRef]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@23:30 - no applicable action for [AppenderRef], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Loggers][logger][AppenderRef]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@26:23 - no applicable action for [logger], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Loggers][logger]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@27:33 - no applicable action for [AppenderRef], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Loggers][logger][AppenderRef]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@28:30 - no applicable action for [AppenderRef], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Loggers][logger][AppenderRef]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@31:23 - no applicable action for [logger], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Loggers][logger]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@32:33 - no applicable action for [AppenderRef], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Loggers][logger][AppenderRef]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@33:30 - no applicable action for [AppenderRef], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Loggers][logger][AppenderRef]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@36:23 - no applicable action for [logger], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Loggers][logger]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@37:33 - no applicable action for [AppenderRef], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Loggers][logger][AppenderRef]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@38:30 - no applicable action for [AppenderRef], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Loggers][logger][AppenderRef]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@41:23 - no applicable action for [logger], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Loggers][logger]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@42:33 - no applicable action for [AppenderRef], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Loggers][logger][AppenderRef]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@43:30 - no applicable action for [AppenderRef], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Loggers][logger][AppenderRef]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@46:23 - no applicable action for [logger], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Loggers][logger]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@47:33 - no applicable action for [AppenderRef], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Loggers][logger][AppenderRef]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@48:30 - no applicable action for [AppenderRef], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Loggers][logger][AppenderRef]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@51:23 - no applicable action for [root], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Loggers][root]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@52:33 - no applicable action for [AppenderRef], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Loggers][root][AppenderRef]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@53:30 - no applicable action for [AppenderRef], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Loggers][root][AppenderRef]]
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:169)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithSpecificConfig(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:66)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:57)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:311)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:281)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:239)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:216)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:80)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
        at com.shc.ecom.ons.listener.OnsListenerApplication.main(OnsListenerApplication.java:15)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:109)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:109)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected:
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@3:13 - no applicable action for [Appenders], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Appenders]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@5:47 - no applicable action for [Console], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Appenders][Console]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@7:79 - no applicable action for [PatternLayout], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][Appenders][Console][PatternLayout]]
```

I am stuck here as I am not able to figure out what I did wrong. This is my first spring boot application.
And for reference, this is my POM file

```
Pom.xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-kafka.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ca.pjer</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-awslogs-appender</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring. Also why all the exclusions (Logback is the default log system used). That being said your config is wrong `AppenderRef` doesn't exists, should be `appender-ref`. Nor a `Loggers` or `Appenders` element looks like you are trying to use a Log4j2 syntax with Logback.